# PhantomJS dynamic view port height

Tags: css, height, width, phantomjs, viewport

I have a simple question about trying to understand PhantomJS viewport behaviour.

```
page.open("https://www.reddit.com", function (status) {
    page.render("c:\\aaa\\a.jpeg", {format: 'jpeg', quality: '100'});
});
```

With this script, I did not specify any view port. So the default according to documentation is 400x300. But the image it generates for me is: 471x4268 pixels.

This is awesome because I did not have to specify the size and Phantom took a full screen shot (even though in a regular browser, you get a scrollbar and not all the page is visible).

The problem is: when I use the same on my internal website, Phantom truncates the site to 400x300 - even though a regular browser shows the same behaviour for Reddit and my internal site i.e. there is a scroll bar and you have to scroll to see the entire content.

The mystery probably lies in CSS used - but can someone explain this difference in behaviour?

Since our internal website pages are all variable "height" and I do not know the viewport height, I would like PhantomJS to do what it does for "reddit" site - even though all the examples around the web will seem to indicate that it will truncate Reddit site to 400x300 if you do not specify a viewport size.

There are all sorts of hacks on the web where for certain sites, you tell the phantomjs browser scroll down "view port size" at a time and take snapshots and then merge the jpegs together - but all those are just silly! It will be nice if PhantomJS did what it does for "Reddit" site i.e. dynamically take the shot of entire web page even though height is pretty large e.g. 4268 pixels.

Here is the example where the page gets truncated to 300 pixels in height.

```
page.open("https://groups.google.com/forum/#!overview", function (status) {
    page.render("c:\\aaa\\a.jpeg", {format: 'jpeg', quality: '100'});
});
```

Comment: Here is an example where you can see PhantomJS truncates the height to 300:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!overview

Comment: It depends on where `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` are used, but not everything can be explained by this. There are many more factors.

Comment: I would love an answer for this as well. I'm using phantomJS and need to render tables containing data. The data can be anywhere from one line to 250 odd lines.Need to adjust the height/ width of the viewport based on the data that comes in.